# Adding a bitwise virtual column to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, bit-manipulation

I'm building this RoR site on an existing database. The user model on database has a column called "secret", which is a bitwise integer that holds information of the columns user has set as secret (first name, last name, etc).

Variables are to the power of two, for example: last name = 1<<1 = 2, first name = 1<<2 = 4, email == 1<<3 = 8, etc. So if user has set first name & email as secret, the column value becomes 4+8 = 12.

Now, I'm trying to find a generalized way to implement these virtual columns into a Rails model. So that, I could do (just a dummy example, the point being, i want to retrieve & store the status):

```
if user.secret_email?
  user.secret_name_last = true
  user.secret_name_first = false
end
```

How to implement these virtual columns neatly to a model (without modifying the existing database)? Current I've got following. It works, but it's not neat. As I've got 20 secret columns, the code looks very *ugly*.

```
  SECRET_NAME_LAST    = (1 << 1) # 2
  attr_accessible :secret_name_last
  def secret_name_last; secret & SECRET_NAME_LAST > 0 unless secret.nil?; end
  def secret_name_last=(value); secret_set_value(SECRET_NAME_LAST, value); end

  SECRET_NAME_FIRST   = (1 << 2) # 4
  attr_accessible :secret_name_first
  def secret_name_first; secret & SECRET_NAME_FIRST > 0 unless secret.nil?; end
  def secret_name_first=(value); secret_set_value(SECRET_NAME_FIRST, value); end

  SECRET_EMAIL        = (1 << 3) # 8
  attr_accessible :secret_email
  def secret_email; secret & SECRET_EMAIL > 0 unless secret.nil?; end
  def secret_email=(value); secret_set_value(SECRET_EMAIL, value); end

  ***snip (17 more)***

  private
  def secret_set_value(item, value)
    if self.secret.nil?
      self.secret = 0
    end

    if value == "1" || value == true || value == 1
      # Add item to secret column (if it doesn't exist)
      if self.secret & item == 0
        self.secret += item
      end
    else
      # Remove item from secret column (if it exists)
      if self.secret & item > 0
        self.secret -= item
      end
    end
  end
```

It would be *great* of I could just do something like:

```
as_bitwise :secret_name_first, :column=>'secret', :value=>4
as_bitwise :secret_name_last,  :column=>'secret', :value=>2
```

Or even,

```
as_bitwise :secret, { :secret_name_last=>4, :secret_name_first=>2 }
```

**EDIT**

Based on Brandan's excellent answer, this is what I've got currently:

```
  module BitwiseColumn
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def bitwise_column(*args)
        mapping = args.extract_options!
        column_name = args.shift
        real_column_name = args.shift

        logger.debug "Initializing bitwisecolumn, column: " + column_name.to_s

        mapping.each_pair do |attribute, offset|
          logger.debug "\tSetting a pair: offset: " + offset.to_s + ", " + attribute.to_s
          mask = 2 ** offset

          class_eval %{
            attr_accessible :#{column_name}_#{attribute}
            def #{column_name}_#{attribute}?
              #{real_column_name} & #{mask} > 0 unless #{real_column_name}.nil?
            end

            def #{column_name}_#{attribute}=(value)
              if self.#{real_column_name}.nil?
                self.#{real_column_name} = 0
              end

              if value == "1" || value == true || value == 1
                if self.#{real_column_name} & #{mask} == 0
                  self.#{real_column_name} += #{mask}
                end
              else
                if self.#{real_column_name} & #{mask} > 0
                  self.#{real_column_name} -= #{mask}
                end
              end
            end
          }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

This allows me to use:

```
  bitwise_column :secret, :realsecretcolumnatdatabase, :name_last=>1, :name_first=>2, :email=>3, :picture=>5, :dob=>6, :place=>12
```

After that, I can call User.first.secret_name_last? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `class_eval` to DRY up your code quite a bit. I'd also suggest factoring this behavior into some kind of a module separate from your `User` class so that you can test it thoroughly and separately from other `User`-specific behavior.

Like you, I tend to start these kinds of tasks with the desired API and work backwards. I started with this in my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BitwiseColumn

  bitwise_column :secret, :first_name => 1, :last_name => 2
end
```

The hash passed to `bitwise_column` maps the virtual attribute names to their mask value as an exponent. I felt like that was easier to manage than having to remember the powers of 2 myself :-)

Then I created the mixin:

```
module BitwiseColumn
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def bitwise_column(*args)
      mapping = args.extract_options!
      column_name = args.shift

      mapping.each_pair do |attribute, offset|
        mask = 2 ** offset

        class_eval %{
          def secret_#{attribute}?
            #{column_name} & #{mask} > 0 unless #{column_name}.nil?
          end

          def secret_#{attribute}=(value)
            if self.#{column_name}.nil?
              self.#{column_name} = 0
            end

            if value == "1" || value == true || value == 1
              if self.#{column_name} & #{mask} == 0
                self.#{column_name} += #{mask}
              end
            else
              if self.#{column_name} & #{mask} > 0
                self.#{column_name} -= #{mask}
              end
            end
          end
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This mixin creates two instance methods for each virtual attribute, one with a `?` and one with a `=`, since that seems to be what you're after. I used your existing logic for the bitwise operations, which seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Excellent! This is a life saver! :) It seems to work if I put the code directly into the class user, but couldn't figure out yet where to put the library code (rails 3.1). To /lib/bitwise_column.rb?

(I also refactored the code a bit, new version included in my initial question).

Comment: My normal convention is to place application-specific mixins and classes in `app/concerns` and reusable mixins and classes in `lib`. If you don't anticipate using this outside of this application, you should probably put it somewhere under `app`. If you do put it in `lib`, you'll need to add `lib` to your `autoload_paths` in `config/application.rb`, since it's no longer automatically included in Rails 3.

Comment: Thank you. Works now, needed to enable the autoload function.